# RegEx to match any character at the 3rd position

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match (extract) any character/symbol at the 3rd position of a string using regex.  And no, I can't use substrings for this scenario.  Below are examples I want matched:

```
ABCDEF => C
123456 => 3
A B C  => B
```

I'm also being guaranteed to have a string of more than 10 characters so I don't have to worry about being less that 3 characters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `^..(.)` and extract capture group #1

Comment: I'm not sure if the underlying program knows how to extract group 1.  All I know is it only does a match

Comment: If lookbehind is supported then use: `(?<=^..).`

Comment: no, look behind doesn't look to be supported

Comment: actually that worked!  go ahead and create an answer and I'll mark it correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<=^..).
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1jXzvY/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=^..)`: Lookbehind assertion to match any 2 characters at line start
- `.`: Match character at 3rd position